# Best algorithm for scheduling interviews

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, ischedulingservice

I want to think about the best algorithm which let the interviewer meet maximum number of candidates.
Suppose that there are n candidates and one interviewer. Each of interview will be held for a fixed time, so we can consider that each interview to be given a time slot. Number of time slots are given as m. All **candidates** are asked to submit whether they are available for each time slots.
If I put it in table format, it looks like this.

```
1: available
0: not available

         Aoi   Banri  ...   Nami
slot 1    1      1    ...    0
slot 2    0      1    ...    1
 .        .      .    .      .
 .        .      .     .     .
 .        .      .      .    .
slot m    0      1    ...    0
```

- Possible approaches 1: solve as a matrix problem

If I interpret this as a matrix problem, it would be reduced to find the Matrix X, expressed as a product of matrices with only one-to-one column exchange, that maximizes trace(AXI).
A is the schedule table, and I is the identity matrix.

Is there any good way to do that?

- Possible approaches 2: solve as an algorithm problem

If one can think about the best algorithm which always produces best result, it does not necessarily be a matrix problem
One that comes to my mind will be something like that:

1. Find the candidate A which has minimum number of available time slots.
2. Among the time slots when A is available, find the slot a which has minimum number of candidates who are possible to attend.
3. Place A on slot a. Remove both from the table.
4. Repeat above procedure for each candidates.

In the Python code format, it may look like this.

```
d=[[Aoi, 1, 0, ..., 0
Banri, 1, 1, ..., 1
.
.
.
Nami,  0, 1, ..., 0
]]

d_reserved=[]

d_return=reserve_each(d, d_reserved)


def reserve_each(d, _reserved):
  d_summed = cal_sums(d) # add summ on rows and columns as the outermost row/column.
  d=d[np.argsort(d_summed[-1, :])]

  for i in range(n):
    di=d[i,1:]
    if np.max(di) < 0.1:
      if i > 1:
        researve_each(d[i-1:, :], d[:i-1,:])
      else:
        # alert!!! perhaps goes random?

    di=di[np.argmax(d[-1,1:]*d[i,1:])]

    first = 1
    for dij in di:
      if dij == 1:
        dij = dij*first
        first = 0        

    d[i,1:]=di

  return np.concatenate(d_reserved, d, axis=1))    


def cal_sums(d):
  d=np.concatenate(d, np.sum(d[:, 1:], axis=1))
  d_summed=np.concatenate(d_sorted, [0, np.sum(d[1, 1:], axis=0)])
  return d_summed
```

However, I can think many ways this algorithm would fail or may not be provide the best answers.
I would be happy if anyone facing similar problem knows better ways to do that.

Comment: I think you should ask this on https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not sure after reading - is there one interviewer and many candidates? Later you wrote "All interviewers"...

Comment: OK, it is `Maximum Bipartite Matching` problem. Look for Kuhn's algorithm or Maximum Flow algorithms

Comment: Crossposted to OR.SE: [Best algorithm for scheduling interviews](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/10581/491)

Answer (score 1):

You can use maximum bipartite matching but this is quite similar to interval colouring so using that might be more efficient.

```
Sort the intervals by their start times, breaking ties arbitrarily
Let I_1, I_2,..., In denote the intervals in this order
For j = 1, 2, 3, ... , n
  For each interval I_i that precedes I_j in sorted order and overlaps it
    Exclude the label of I_i from consideration for I_j
  Endfor
  If there is any label from {1, 2,..., d} that has not been excluded then
    Assign a nonexcluded label to I_j
  Else
    Leave I_j unlabeled
  Endif
Endfor
```

This is the pseudocode for the algorithm from Algorithm Design by K&T p.g. 124